# gnome-terminal: keep track of directory in new tab

Tags: shell, cd-command, gnome-terminal

I'm on Arch linux, and when I open a new terminal tab, it always goes to `$HOME`. How can I make it so that when I open a new tab, it opens the shell in the directory I was in previously?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1193993) related to this issue

All you need to do is add the following line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`:

```
. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

At least on Arch, the script checks if you are running either bash or zsh and exits if you are not.

Comment: It should be noted that this might not have an effect, unless it is added after `export PROMPT_COMMAND=...`, if such a thing already exists in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` overrides the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable. To fix this, you can modify `vte.sh`, and change the part with `PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"` to `PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND};__vte_prompt_command"`

Comment: I've been careful to put this in the right place, check that the script exists, etc, but it does not have the desired effect. I'm running 4.2.3-1-ARCH with Gnome Terminal 3.18.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't work for me for zsh when adding it to my ``.zshrc``. I'm using oh-my-zsh, not sure if that is related.

Comment: I'm using oh-my-zsh. I've up to date on arch as of at most a couple weeks. Check out my dotfiles repo to compare: https://github.com/korylprince/dotfiles

Comment: @humanityANDpeace  sorry to hear that. It looks like zsh doesn't suffer from this issue.

Comment: @korylprince I have to retract my earlier comment, after having looked into the matter more (indeed after patching the source of `gnome-terminal` to guess the cwd from the `/proc/$SHELLSPID/@cwd`) to find eventually some more background. The solution you gave is the very right way after all. Even though the word **bug** or **regression** comes up with the change, it is indeed somewhat advantages compared to tracking the PID of the shell subprocess' PID. Gnome VTE project (internally used by gnome-terminal) tracks CWDchanges via reading encoded data emited by the shell prompt,hence the`.bashrc`

Comment: @humanityANDpeace good to hear! Sounds like you had an adventure :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me. Perhaps it's outdated?

Comment: @sigvaldm I'm not sure what to tell you. I'm using `vte.sh` from the `vte-common` arch linux package. I'm using zsh, and sourcing the `vte.sh` file in `.zshrc` makes the difference in tabs working correctly. I'm using `GNOME Terminal 3.28.1 using VTE 0.52.1 +GNUTLS`. You can see my full dot files at https://github.com/korylprince/dotfiles

Comment: @korylprince I'm sorry, this was all my bad. I added `vte.sh` to `.zshrc`, closed the window, and tried `File -> Open Terminal` from another window which I'd forgotten to close (feeling silly). It works now :)

Comment: It worked for me! Thanks a lot it will save a lot of frustration at work! Can someone explain why this fix works?

Comment: This happens in the __vte_osc7 function (for zsh) in /etc/profile.d/vte.sh. It prints an escape sequence that gnome-terminal uses to set the directory.

Answer (score 10):

Might as well crosspost [this](https://superuser.com/questions/232835/open-a-new-tab-in-the-same-directory) hacky solution from superuser:

> [This] saves the current folder in a file, after every command (Doesn't hurt too much IMO)
>   and opens a new terminal in the saved current folder.
>
> add the following to *.zshrc* [or *.bashrc*]

```
# emulate bash PROMPT_COMMAND (only for zsh)
precmd() { eval "$PROMPT_COMMAND" }
# open new terminal in same dir
PROMPT_COMMAND='pwd > "${HOME}/.cwd"'
[[ -f "${HOME}/.cwd" ]] && cd "$(< ${HOME}/.cwd)"
```

Note that this you will also put you in your last-used directory when opening a new *window*.

Comment: Worked great for me. Solus Linux, gnome-terminal, and zshell.

Comment: Works great for me too, I'm using the default Elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki terminal, thanks.

Comment: To fix the (mostly negligible) performance impact of saving a file on an actual disk it could be saved on a tmpfs mount. It is lost upon reboot but that seems fine to me.

Comment: Worked for me on macOS, zsh

Answer (score 0):

@swalog inspired me in his [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/gnome-terminal-keep-track-of-directory-in-new-tab#comment219157_93477) to strip down all unnecessary parts of the `vte.sh` while not modifying the the prompt nor the terminal title.  Note that I don’t use `zsh`, therefore I removed `zsh`-related code.

```bsh
# Copyright © 2006 Shaun McCance <shaunm@gnome.org>
# Copyright © 2013 Peter De Wachter <pdewacht@gmail.com>
#
# This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

# 28 Sep 2019: Tukusej’s Sirs modified this by stripping down all unnecessary parts for his usage
# (src: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/gnome-terminal-keep-track-of-directory-in-new-tab#comment219157_93477)

# Not an interactive shell?
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return 0

# Not running under vte?
[ "${VTE_VERSION:-0}" -ge 3405 ] || return 0

__vte_urlencode() (
    # This is important to make sure string manipulation is handled
    # byte-by-byte.
    LC_ALL=C
    str="$1"
    while [ -n "$str" ]; do
        safe="${str%%[!a-zA-Z0-9/:_\.\-\!\'\(\)~]*}"
        printf "%s" "$safe"
        str="${str#"$safe"}"
        if [ -n "$str" ]; then
            printf "%%%02X" "'$str"
            str="${str#?}"
        fi
    done
)

__vte_prompt_command() {
    local command=$(HISTTIMEFORMAT= history 1 | sed 's/^ *[0-9]\+ *//')
    command="${command//;/ }"
    local pwd='~'
    printf "\033]7;file://%s%s\007" "${HOSTNAME:-}" "$(__vte_urlencode "${PWD}")"
}

case "$TERM" in
    xterm*|vte*)
        [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND};__vte_prompt_command"
        ;;
esac
```