# Gnome-terminal and Zsh: keep current directory on new tab/window

Tags: gnome, zsh, gnome-terminal, cd-command

I'm running gnome 3.10.1 on Arch with Zsh.
I'm facing that problem that when I create a new tab or window from a terminal window, it resets the current dir to my home dir.

I've already tried this: [gnome-terminal: keep track of directory in new tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/gnome-terminal-keep-track-of-directory-in-new-tab), but it didn't work.

I tought that maybe it could be some configuration on my `.zshrc` file, so, I cleaned it up and put just the following line:

```
. /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

However, it didn't work as expected.

Yes, this file exists and here is its contents:

```
# Copyright © 2006 Shaun McCance <shaunm@gnome.org>
# Copyright © 2013 Peter De Wachter <pdewacht@gmail.com>
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307, USA.

# Not bash or zsh?
[ -n "$BASH_VERSION" -o -n "$ZSH_VERSION" ] || return 0

# Not an interactive shell?
[[ $- == *i* ]] || return 0

# Not running under vte?
[ "${VTE_VERSION:-0}" -ge 3405 ] || return 0

__vte_urlencode() (
  # This is important to make sure string manipulation is handled
  # byte-by-byte.
  LC_ALL=C
  str="$1"
  while [ -n "$str" ]; do
    safe="${str%%[!a-zA-Z0-9/:_\.\-\!\'\(\)~]*}"
    printf "%s" "$safe"
    str="${str#"$safe"}"
    if [ -n "$str" ]; then
      printf "%%%02X" "'$str"
      str="${str#?}"
    fi
  done
)

# Print a warning so that anyone who's added this manually to his PS1 can adapt.
# The function will be removed in a later version.
__vte_ps1() {
  echo -n "(__vte_ps1 is obsolete)"
}

__vte_osc7 () {
  printf "\033]7;file://%s%s\a" "${HOSTNAME:-}" "$(__vte_urlencode "${PWD}")"
}

__vte_prompt_command() {
  printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007%s" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}" "$(__vte_osc7)"
}

case "$TERM" in
  xterm*|vte*)
    [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ] && PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command" 
    [ -n "$ZSH_VERSION"  ] && chpwd_functions+=(__vte_osc7)
    ;;
esac

true
```

This is really bugging me...

Is there any solution?

Comment: It is related to gnome-terminal, not to zsh. It seems to be a [reported bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1193993), although the bug behind the link is ubuntu-gnome's bug.

Comment: have you tried `terminator`?

Comment: Yeah, terminator works fine, but, for example, `nautilus-open-terminal` extension always open gnome-terminal, I've not been able to change it...

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I had to restart gnome-terminal after sourcing vte.sh in my rc-file. Didn't work just by saving it and opening a new tab/window.. (using bash/arch/gnome3.10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you have to enable the *"Run command as a login shell"* option in order to make it work like it should.

The print bellow is in Portuguese, but this is the configuration I've got it to work.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this would work, because you are not using zsh

Answer (score 18):

I don't know if you're still running into this issue, but I found my problem was I was running /bin/zsh as a custom command in my terminal profile. Disabling that fixed the issue for me - and still kept zsh as my primary shell.

[image: Terminal Profile]

Comment: Exactly solved the problem for me using Fedora, thanks a lot!

Comment: changing that would mean using the default bash instead of zsh. so how does that fix the issue?

Comment: @Alfie The user is not using their default shell (probably `bash`). That means that the command that is executed to set the prompt (set up at login in `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh`) is not the right one and the terminal is not aware of the shell's current directory.

Comment: The screenshot is not up to date anymore. The second option does not exist anymore; ticking the first one did the trick. It's the default, but you have to set ZSH as your default shell with `chsh`, I presume.