# Spawn new terminal window with the same directory as the previous window

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, gnome-terminal, awesome

I'm running Awesome WM on the latest Arch Linux with Gnome Terminal and the default bash. I've managed to get this working, but I wonder if any form of improvement is possible with this implementation. The question does **NOT** relate to opening new tabs, only to spawning new terminal windows with Awesome WM.

I have rewritten the "cd" command to save the current working directory in the ".cd_extend" file:

**~/.bashrc**

```
alias cd='source ~/.cd_extend'
```

**~/.cd_extend**

```
#!/bin/bash

command cd $1
echo $(pwd) > ~/.terminal_directory
```

When I spawn a new terminal, the ".terminal_directory" is read and appended as an argument to gnome terminal's "--working-directory" flag.

**~/.dotfiles/open_terminal.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR=$(cat ~/.terminal_directory)
gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR
```

**awesomewm rc.lua**

```
terminal   = "~/.dotfiles/open_terminal.sh"
awful.key({ modkey, }, "Return", function () awful.util.spawn(terminal) end)
```

I wonder if I have missed any internal bash functionality which could have simplified this and if there is room for improvement.

Comment: Note: `echo $(pwd)` is just a complicated way of spelling `pwd`. Another quick fix is that you should at least use `command cd "$1"` instead of `command cd $1` in case the argument has spaces in it.

Comment: I thought that outputting to a file was only possible with echo. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gnome-terminal: keep track of directory in new tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/gnome-terminal-keep-track-of-directory-in-new-tab)

Comment: @Ashok The question that you're referring to has nothing to do with spawning new terminal windows in Awesome WM. The question is related to gnome-terminal tabs. I have edited the question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of testing and asking around, this seems to be the easiest implementation. It could be done with a global state which Awesome WM reads, however to keep predictability and ease of implementation I'm keeping this.

**~/.bashrc**

```
function cd {
  command cd "$1"
  pwd > /tmp/terminal_pwd
}
```

Afterwards I can open the terminal, which reads from the `/tmp/terminal_pwd` file and opens a new gnome shell with the given working directory.

**Awesome WM - rc.lua**

```
 -- Terminal
  awful.key({ modkey, }, 'Return',
    function()
      awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell(
        "if [[ -s /tmp/terminal_pwd ]]; then cat /tmp/terminal_pwd; else echo '~'; fi",
        function(path)
          awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell('gnome-terminal --working-directory '..path, function() end)
        end)
    end),
```

Comment: (1) Since you’re running the `~/.cd_extend` file with the `source` command, you don’t need a “shebang” (`#!/bin/bash`) in it. (It is harmless; it will be ignored.)  (2) The `gnome-terminal` command should say `--working-directory="$DIR"` (with quotes).

Comment: thanks @G-Man, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: with `command cd "$1"` with double quotes affect the basic behavior - `cd` without arguments not move you to the home directory. without quotes works as expected.

Answer (score 9):

On Arch Linux + GNOME (at least), you can add the following line into `~/.bashrc` to have new Terminal windows opened in the current directory:

```
source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh
```

There is already a [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93476/gnome-terminal-keep-track-of-directory-in-new-tab) about new tabs. It turns out that the answer is the same for new windows.

Comment: It’s not clear how this answers the question.  What does this do?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete (i.e., to explain how this answers the question).

Comment: It precisely answers the asked question. I have nothing to add, except that I just thank you for your downvote.

Comment: It does not answer the question as it is related to tabs, and not new windows spawned by Awesome WM as noted in my question. Therefore you're answer should elaborate more as to why sourcing vte.sh solves retaining directory state between Awesome WM spawns.

Comment: Apparently gnome-terminal changed its implementation so this no longer happens by default.  The shell is responsible for handling this.  `/etc/profile.d/vte.sh` sets $PROMPT_COMMAND to do a printf to handle this.  If you set $PROMPT_COMMAND, then you must ensure that it calls the function in vte.sh.  See [this ticket](https://midnight-commander.org/ticket/3088?cversion=0&cnum_hist=7) for more

Answer (score 5):

In the menu of Gnome-terminal, use:

```
File --> Open Terminal
```

That will open a new window using the pwd as the directory.

Also, you may set the open tabs:

> Edit --> Preferences --> General --> Open new terminals in: --> select tab.

So new terminals will open in the same window with the same pwd.
You will still be able to open new windows if needed:

> Alt-F2 --> gnome-terminal

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this breaks the flow with awesome, because awesome should be spawning the terminals, otherwise I'm required to bind my keys for a new terminal through gnome-terminal, which is not desired. Also using Alt-F2 is a bit hard as i'm missing the Fn buttons.

Comment: This option seems to be missing in gnome-terminal 3.22 :/

Comment: On the Gnome-terminal 3.22.2 I have it is still valid, shrug :/.

Comment: The simple solution is, just add this line to the _~/.bashrc_. `source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh`

Answer (score 4):

I am using **i3** and if I do the normal <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then it opens a new terminal in the home directory. But, if I am already in a terminal and I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> then a new terminal opens in the last terminal's directory.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is the shortcut for opening a new window on the terminal (my terminal is **gnome-terminal**).

I understand this question is regarding AwesomeWM and the terminal other's use may not have this key binding but sharing just in case it may help someone.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: The simple solution is, just add this line to the ~/.bashrc. source /etc/profile.d/vte.sh

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to run command from terminal:

`gnome-terminal $(pwd)`

That works great under i3wm for me, so you can alias this (in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile) to anything you desire, something like:

```
alias new='gnome-terminal $(pwd)'
```

Haven't tested under Awesome WM, but shall do the same thing I believe, very busy working on the project, so can't relly test it now. Will do in future for sure

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work for this question. Because i'm spawning a new terminal window from an active Awesome WM session, This only works if you run it from the terminal.